# How to reference ItemGroup Identity within the definition of the var

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-target

I have a target like below. It needs to replace content of a file with new content. I have multiple files I am matching with ItemGroup.
I couldn't figure out a way to get this working.

Here is my target definition.

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <PRSetting Include="$(settings_root)\**\settings_config_*.xml">
        <NewContent>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('%(Identity)')).Replace('[config.version]', '$(PR_Version)'))</NewContent>
      </PRSetting>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="PrepSettings" Inputs="@(PRSetting)" 
                              Outputs="@(PRSetting->'$out\$Filename.xml')" >

    <Message Text="%(PRSetting.Identity) new contents:" />
    <Message Text="%(PRSetting.NewContent)"/>
  </Target>
```

I hope I explained it right what I am trying to do. When the target is built, I am getting an error that the path to File::ReadFile() can't be empty string. I am using VS 2019. This is work in progress. I am yet to figure out how to save the new content in destination file.

**Update**
I have the Itemgroup outside. I updated the question. The reason it is outside is because the target inputs parameter needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and see if it works:

```
  <Target Name="PrepSettings">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PRSetting Include="$(settings_root)\**\settings_config_*.xml" />
      <PRSetting>
        <NewContent Condition="%(Identity) != ''">$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('%(Identity)')).Replace('[config.version]', '$(PR_Version)'))</NewContent>
      </PRSetting>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="@(PRSetting.Identity) new contents:" />
    <Message Text="%(PRSetting.NewContent)"/>
  </Target>
```

There are two changes:

1. There seems to be an issue with an `Include` that doesn't use an existing `ItemGroup` and metadata that is self-referencing. So, setting up `PRSetting` is split in two.

   - First, establish `PRSetting` with the `Include`.
   - Second, revisit to add the `NewContent` metadata item.
2. Add `Condition="%(Identity) != ''"` on the `NewContent` metadata.

I'm not able to fully test your exact scenario at present but I tested an analogue.

Here is my test analogue:

```
  <Target Name="PrepSettings">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PRSetting Include="1;4;2;3"/>
      <PRSetting>
        <NewContent Condition="%(Identity) != ''">$([MSBuild]::Add('%(Identity)', '1'))</NewContent>
      </PRSetting>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="PRSetting is @(PRSetting->'(%(Identity),%(NewContent))');" />
  </Target>
```

The output is

```
PrepSettings:
  PRSetting is (1,2);(4,5);(2,3);(3,4);
```

Regarding your code change to move the `ItemGroup` outside the target:

- The technique of splitting the `ItemGroup` as written won't work, but if you are using VS2017 or later and working with .NET Core/.NET 5+ you can use `Update`.
- As shown in the question, the `Outputs` attribute has syntax errors. I assume `Outputs="@(PRSetting->'$(OutputPath)\%(Filename).xml')"` (or something close) is intended.
- As shown in the question, the `Outputs` attribute will never be satisfied because `PrepSettings` doesn't create the files. I assume `PrepSettings` as shown is not complete.

Comment: Tried it. NewContent is always evaluating to empty string. That is because %Identity check in ItemGroup was false.

Comment: Are you saying that `%(Identity) != ''` evaluated to false? In my testing that could only happen when the wildcards in the `Include` attribute fail to match any files. If you add a `Message` task before the `ItemGroup`, does `$(settings_root)` have the value you expect it to?

Comment: I have the item group defined outside target as I have a reference to it in the target's inputs parameter. I updated the question. 
The Message line is printing expected file names.

Comment: Moving the `ItemGroup` outside the target changes the order. When MSBuild loads a project, all `ItemGroup`s and `PropertyGroup`s that are outside of targets are evaluated and a dependency graph of targets is created. MSBuild then executes the targets in dependent order.  `ItemGroup`s and `PropertyGroup`s that are inside of targets are not evaluated until the target is executed.